# How to make each computer only upload 3 images per day? (using PHP)

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I'm building an image-uploading website. One of the limitation is that each computer user can only upload 3 images per day. I prefer not to use both session and cookie, because if the user close the browser, the session will destroy; the user can also remove the cookie through the browser setting. So is there any better idea to achieve this limitation?

Comment: Anything you do on the client can be changed by the client, so it is nothing more than security through obscurity. This needs to be done server-side, which means using a database. And even then, people can use proxies and make it appear like their IP address has changed.

Comment: Is it possible to set cookies into session?

Comment: there is no 100% reliable way of doing this. http is stateless, and cookies are how state is established. either you force people to use an account and tie the limit to that account, or you resign yourself that some people are going to bypass your 'restriction' and upload more than the limit allows